# Freemarker processing of included template

Tags: java, freemarker

I have freemaker template

```
<#import "includes/header.ftl" as header>

<h1>${title}</h1>
```

in header.ftl is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

and I have really simple code to render it

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
File dir = new File("/usr/cms/data/templates");
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(dir);
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
input.put("title","Test title");

Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
template.process(input,writer);
```

Template is processed but header.ftl is not included in string inside StringWriter.

How to force freemarker to include #included files during processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to include a file, you should use `#include`, not `#import`. For example:

```
<#include "includes/header.ftl">
```

See the [Freemarker manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html).